# Get height of tab bar on any device in React-Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'd like to position a component just above the createBottomTabNavigator TabBar in React-Navigation V2.

The height of the tab bar seems to differ on various devices (iOS devices especially). Is there a way to calculate the height of the tab bar as it is displayed on a device?

Comment: What do you mean by `calculate the height of the tab bar` ? You want to override default configuration. Right?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get the height of the bottom tab bar so that I know how to absolutely position a component above it without that component being cut off. I'm currently having issues on iOS with that tab bar being taller on iPhone X.

Answer (score 19):

### React Navigation 5 +

You now have two options to get the height of the bottomTabBar.

To get the height of the bottom tab bar, you can use BottomTabBarHeightContext with React's Context API or useBottomTabBarHeight, which is a custom Hook:

```
import { BottomTabBarHeightContext } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

// ...

<BottomTabBarHeightContext.Consumer>
  {tabBarHeight => (
    /* render something */
  )}
</BottomTabBarHeightContext.Consumer>
```

or

```
import { useBottomTabBarHeight } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

// ...

const tabBarHeight = useBottomTabBarHeight();
```

Make sure you use version `5.11.9` or greater

Comment: This answer must be highlighted.
Great job. Thank you @Tom Bombadil

Comment: For others who get the error "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks...", make sure you are calling useBottomTabBarHeight() at the top of the function, and not inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Comment: 3 years later and this is still a huge help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

As you check the [source code for `react-navigation-tabs`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/blob/d2aa789109ed0df61c0c0ac7b759ac386a720804/src/views/BottomTabBar.js#L239) which react-navigation [uses for `createBottomTabNavigator`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/2643f690a98ecf9394ffa2f3671795feabc989f3/src/react-navigation.js#L58), you can see that there is only 2 different bottom tab bar heights. Compact and default, which [changes between some conditions](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/blob/d2aa789109ed0df61c0c0ac7b759ac386a720804/src/views/BottomTabBar.js#L181). You can also set your component's position according to these conditions manually.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to also get the unused distance below the tab bar too? 

For instance on iPhone X, the tab bar displays with its normal height, but there's 2-3x the height in unused space below it. I need to know the total height in order to place my component above that.

Comment: @LiamKelly I think the mentioned space is caused by [`SafeAreaView`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/handling-iphonex.html) which helps content to show correctly on iPhone X. You can check the source code for it [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-safe-area-view/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Not an excellent answer because there is only an link and not the actual answer. Include the answer AND the link where one can find the source is how an answer should be. Thanks @yungGun!

Answer (score 4):

To avoid Ipnone X issues they use `react-native-safe-area-view` inside.

You just need to know padding at bottom:

```
import { getInset } from 'react-native-safe-area-view'
const bottomOffset = getInset('bottom')
```

It solved problem for us.

We also use specific component position.

**Updated according to library update:**

```
import { SafeAreaConsumer } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

<SafeAreaConsumer>
   {insets => (
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
               paddingBottom: 11 + insets.bottom,
          }}
        >
          ...
      </TouchableOpacity>
   )}
</SafeAreaConsumer>
```

or hook:

```
const insets = useSafeArea();
```

Comment: Not working anymore, they moved to a different module which doesn't export that function.

Comment: @ffritz migration attached

Comment: Thanks, however this inset does **not** include the tab bar. It returns the bottom starting point of the tab bar (34 on iPhone 11) .

Comment: If you're lucky enough to be using functional components (i.e. not classes), then the hook is the simplest way to do this. The tab bar heights are limited to 2 sizes, and the offset is what varies.

Answer (score 3):

For your issue of how to position something above the tab bar, you can also achieve this without absolute positioning. This way you aren't relying on how the logic of determining the height of the bar is implemented (which may also change in the future).

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from "react-navigation"

createBottomTabNavigator({
    // Your tabs
}, {
    tabBarComponent: (props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />
})
```

For example, if you wanted a little red bar above your tabs, you could do the following

```
tabBarComponent: (props) => (
    <View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 10 }} />
        <BottomTabBar {...props} />
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by benny points to where you need to go, but doesn't give you an easy way to check if . To complete the answer, I'll elaborate on the exact checks required to know which height to use. First we need to know if the tab bar is in adaptive mode or not. If you haven't passed "adaptive" as a parameter, adaptive is set to true for all iOS devices with iOS 11+. If it's not iOS11+, then adaptive is false. So, if you HAVE NOT passed "adaptive" as a parameter to tabBarOptions, the function is:

```
import {Platform, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const isLandscape = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
    return dim.width >= dim.height;
};
function tabBarHeight() {
    const majorVersion = parseInt(Platform.Version, 10);
    const isIos = Platform.OS === 'ios';
    const isIOS11 = majorVersion >= 11 && isIos;
    if(Platform.isPad) return 49;
    if(isIOS11 && !isLandscape()) return 49;
    return 29;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if your and bennygenel's answer would be merged, but you provide the most useful part. Tha answer is 29 (not 42 because the question is different)

Comment: You forgot + insets.bottom